# format string containing html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple string variable that contains a portion of HTML inside. For example:

```
string contents = "<div><p>Hi how are you. <a href="#">Click here</a> if you want to know more";
```

I want to include this HTML in page:

```
<div class="description">
    @contents
</div>
```

However, it messes up the rest of the page because of unclosed tags.

Is there a function (or a helper) that reads and formats the HTML inside for example, to complete the HTML without errors:

```
@Html.DisplayProperHTML(contents)
```

This will render as:

```
<div><p>Hi how are you. <a href="#">Click here</a> if you want to know more</p></div>
```

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't any helper like this. You must write your own.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such functionality built-in.

You can use the HTML Agility Pack to parse and fix broken HTML.